# Excel Dynamically Add To If Row Contains Something

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I have an excel sheet that is used for customer data entry, such as cost of parts, how much they paid for everything, and how they paid for it (cash, credit, or check).  Here's my first page to get a better look:

[image: Sheet1]

So on the first sheet, you enter all data that you need, such as name, car make, address (the date is dynamic with =TODAY()).  When you type "y" in the confirm box, the data is calculated on sheet2 to analyze the monetary values.  Here's sheet 2 with data so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image]

Pressing the "New Customer" button runs a VBA script that creates a new line on sheet1 for another customer entry, creates another corresponding line on sheet2 for the new line on sheet1 to produce the calculated data, and "stores" both sheet1 and sheet2 of the previous customer data on sheet3.

This leads me to my question.. For sheet2 calculations "Cash Total", "Credit Card Total", and "Check Total", I need to filter through and add only (cash + part cost) if they paid in cash, (card + part cost) if they paid with a card, and (check + part cost) if they paid with a check.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to go row by row and check whether they used cash, card, or credit to pay, and then add the part cost of THAT ROW to the corresponding total box.  I imagine a statement such as =IF(G2 > 0, G2 + E2) or something along those lines would work, but I cannot figure it out and would like to see you guys present some solutions.  Please note, this (part cost + medium of payment) also needs to work for a dynamic range of cells, as the number of customers for the day is unknown, meaning there could be different amounts of rows entered by the "new customer".

Comment: If the other ones are already zero (customers can only have one type of payment) just add all 4 cells together.

Comment: @Chrismas007 The second customer may pay with card instead of cash, and all customer data is displayed/calculated on sheet 2.  So that would ruin your solution.

Comment: Well then you are going to need to share your code so that we get a better understanding of the transition of the data.

Comment: @Chrismas007 All I'm needing to do on sheet2 is add (cash [column G] + part cost [column E] if cash > 0 FOR THAT ROW), and same for card and check.  All of these totals need displayed in "Cash Total", "Card Total", and "Check Total"

Comment: I basically need to go row by row and add the results to the Total boxes.. sounds like a loop for dynamic range, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you could try something like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F2:F7 > 0),D2:D7)+SUM(F2:F7)
```

The SUMPRODUCT adds up the part cost of only the rows that have a cash payment. Then that total is added to the total of the cash column. You would just need to change the F column to the other payment methods for each type.

There really isn't a good way to make it dynamic. Just set the range large enough that you will never go over.

```
F2:F1000
```

I did not write the equation specific to your sheet. Try this for cash totals.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(G2:G1000 > 0),E2:E1000)+SUM(G2:G1000)
```

You also didn't mention anything about multiple payment types. I will think about that and get back to you.

Comment: It isn't working.  What I don't get with your formula is that I am adding column G to E for each row that G >0, and I need "Cash Total" to be a running total of all rows that meet this criteria.  Your formula uses the F column, which isn't right, and the D column, which is irrelevant to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Also, I believe that if I had two customers on sheet2, one paying with cash and another with a card, with your formula it would add both customer "Part costs" to the total because the range of G2:G7 would be greater than 0.. If you know what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: I'm an idiot, changed some of the letters around and it works perfectly.  Disregard my incompetence.

Comment: I updated my equation to match your sheet. I will work on a solution for the multiple payment methods.

Comment: "...For sheet2 calculations "Cash Total", "Credit Card Total", and "Check Total", I need to filter through and add only (cash + part cost) if they paid in cash, (card + part cost) if they paid with a card, and (check + part cost) if they paid with a check." In my post.  But your solution works now with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

As an amendment to bbishopca's statement, you can probably just use the =COUNT(F:F) statement to find out dynamically how many rows exist in the sheet. So right now you'd put

```
=COUNT(F:F)
```

In a cell, say A1, which would output 2. Then set the range from bbishopca's answer to

```
F2:INDIRECT("F"&A1)
```

Repeat for each type of payment.